# Google consent SDK with admob on cordova

Tags: cordova, admob, cordova-plugins

I have developed a app using react and cordova. I am planning on using admob for ads. So I got a admob plugin working from npm, but I can't find any thing that will allow me to use the google consent SDK with cordova.

I want to be GDPR compliant. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/dragonbane0/cordova-plugin-google-consent worked for me, but be aware that you cannot use it on cordova 9 at present because the IOS code uses requireCordovaModule. In addition since dependencies of the consent plugin use the Android X  library format you may experience "D8: Program type already present:" errors. If this occurs then the solution is to use https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx & https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter